# How to ensure that MySQL rows are unique?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a row into a MySQL table, with the condition that the row itself has to be unique. 
So for example, the row would have `id`, `name` and `address`, but we can't have an insert with duplicate name and address.
I tried doing a select before inserting, to make sure I don't find the result, but it doesn't seem to be working.
I am currently trying to do this before inserting:

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE cityId = $cityId AND countyId = $countyId AND stateId = $stateId AND countryId = $countyId AND district = $district;
```

EDIT:
All those fields are allowed to duplicate, they just can't duplicate all at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest solution would be to put a `UNIQUE` constraint on cityId, countyId, stateId, countryId, districtId and then check whether the insert statement was successful.

To quickly test this:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_here ADD UNIQUE INDEX(cityId, stateId, countryId, countyId, districtId);
```

And rerun the insert query. If it encounters a duplicate it will fail, which you will be able to handle in your application.

Comment: those IDs can be duplicates, they just can't duplicate together.

Comment: @chustar: Denis's suggestion satisfies that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a unique index set on the table you can use:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO locations SET cityId = $cityId, countyId = $countyId, stateId = $stateId, countryId = $countyId, district = $district;
```

Answer (score 0):

with such constraints, you should have made the name and address columns as composite primary key..

Comment: Arguable. At least there should be a unique index on the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a better solution. First check the database and check if the IP and name exists by using:

```
$check = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT FROM tablename WHERE name="'.$_POST['name'].'"'));
if($check = 0) //Checks if the name does not exist
{
       // Your code...
}
else
{
       // Error to tell the user the name already exists....
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why you think it's a better solution? Using the existing answer requires one single query, whereas your code needs two queries. So the original is more efficient, but are there other reasons you think your solution is better?